# Proving leaves of a specific foliation of an open set in Euclidean space are the level sets of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

My question is about a possible alternative way of proving that the leaves of a specific foliation are the level sets of a continuous function $\phi$. I believe I have proved this (for general $n$) by appealing to some results in differential geometry, but the proof is rather involved. I wanted to explore whether there was a simpler way. To fix ideas I'll give my example for $n=3$.

So let's say I have a foliation of $R^3_{++}$ (the open set of vectors $(x,y,z)$ with all components strictly positive). This foliation is a result of taking the two vector fields
\begin{eqnarray}
X^1 &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - m^1(x,y,z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
X^2 &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - m^2(x,y,z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z},
\end{eqnarray}
where $m^1,m^2$ are strictly positive $C^2$ functions defined everywhere on $R^3_{++}$, requiring that
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial m^2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial m^1}{\partial y} + m^1 \frac{\partial m^2} {\partial z} - m^2 \frac{\partial m^1}{\partial z} = 0,
\end{equation}
which makes the Lie bracket $[X^1,X^2] = 0$, and applying the Frobenius theorem. I would now like to order these leaves, which would follow trivially if I could find a continuous function $\phi: R^3_{++} \rightarrow R$ so that each leaf $L$ was of the form $L = \phi^{-1}(r)$, for some $r \in R$, with different leaves corresponding to different values of $r$.

As I say, I've tackled this problem and believe I've solved it, but the solution (using differential geometry) was complicated and involved *first* ordering the leaves and *then* constructing $\phi$. Could I instead use an existing technique (I believe it's called "integrating factor") to do the following:  For any $p = (x,y,z) \in R^3_{++}$, let $D_P$ be the plane spanned by $\{X^1,X^2 \}$ at $p$. Then a normal vector to $D_p$ at $p$, call it $N_p$, is any multiple of $(m^1(p),m^2(p),1)$ (say we restrict to positive multiples to set an orientation). Suppose now there existed a function $\mu : R^3_{++} \rightarrow R$ which was everywhere strictly positive and such that the vector field $(\mu(p) m^1(p),\mu(p) m^2(p), \mu(p))$ was such that the 1-form
\begin{equation}
\mu m^1 dx + \mu m^2 dy + \mu dz 
\end{equation}
was exact; i.e. had a potential $\phi(p)$. Then wouldn't $\phi$ be the function I'm looking for? I realize this requires that the system
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial \mu m^2}{\partial z} &=& 0 \\
\frac{\partial \mu m^1}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} &=& 0 \\
\frac{\partial \mu m^2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \mu m^1}{\partial y} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
be solved for the function $\mu$, and that $\mu$ be everywhere strictly positive. Is it trivial, or at least a simple matter to show, that such a solution exists? Or might the cure be worse than the disease? I'm certainly willing to work to solve the problem, but I don't want to go down a rabbit hole and end up doing just as much work using this approach as I did with my first attempt at finding a solution.

**EDIT**: I've done a bit more digging and it seems that the condition given above that $[X^1,X^2] = 0$ is *equivalent* to the normal field having zero curl, which would mean that the 1-form $\mu m^1 dx + \mu m^2 dy + \mu dz$ is exact so that the potential $\phi$ must exist. This then begs the question: Is it automatically true that any foliation (at least of an open set of Euclidean space) arising from a set of commuting vector fields (i.e. Lie brackets zero) must be such that its leaves are the level sets of a function? My mathematical naivete is showing here, but this seems where I'm headed.

Comment: It looks like each leaf is a graph of a function $z(x,y)$, is this right? If so, you could label each leaf by the value $z(1,1)$, for example.

Comment: Well, yes, that is true, thanks. I in fact used that fact to do the ordering. However, my concern is that there is a trivial way to do it; i.e. a potential must exist so that each leaf is automatically a level set.

Comment: Well, a potential certainly does exist, by applying the implicit function theorem: take $\phi(x,y,z)$ to be the $z$-coordinate of the unique leaf through $(x,y,z)$ (which is more-or-less what @MichałMiśkiewicz is suggestion). It sounds like you want an explicit formula for the potential, solved using differential equation methods?

Comment: To me, neither an implicit nor an explicit formula would seem more trivial than the other.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Thanks for commenting. Actually, no, I don't need an explicit formula. My objective was to show that the leaves can be ordered and that a continuous function "representing" that order exists. I understand that for each leaf there is a function $u(x,y)$ such that the leaf is the graph of $u$ (a crucial part of my proof), but by potential I meant (and, again, I apologize if I'm not understanding this) a function $\phi(x,y,z)$ on all of $R^3_{++}$ such that  each leaf $L$ is $\phi^-1(r)$ for some real $r$. If that automatically holds then my objective can be achieved trivially.